# Drop column in BQ table won't drop column from Information schema

Tags: google-bigquery

From BQ table if we drop a column, the output of "select * from table" query won't show the dropped column.
but if we generate the DDL Script from information schema, we still can see the dropped column available in output script.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try recreate table without this column instead

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

https://popsql.com/learn-sql/bigquery/how-to-drop-a-column-in-bigquery